# Latest comment post should be the first post in the blog

Tags: posts

If someone put a comment to post, that post should be the first post of blog. ( Forums works like this).

I don't want to use forum plugin also. I need only, when a user submit a comment, that post goes to up as the first post of my blog.

Is it possible?

Comment: The short answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: You might find this old WP support forum thread useful:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/sort-posts-in-the-loop-by-recent-comments-or-activity?replies=11

Answer (score 0):

WordPress post queries don't natively support [ordering](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) by such specific comment information, only by comment count. Rest of comment-related things aren't stored in posts table and not available for easy querying.

While it's probably possible to cook up SQL for this, I think it would be more practical to store date of comment in its parent post's custom fields and order by that (which is natively supported), via modifying blog archive query in `pre_get_posts` hook or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the post_modified_date of the post on a new comment using this code

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'update_post_modified_date', 10, 2 );
function update_post_modified_date(  $comment_id, $comment ) {
  wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $comment->comment_post_ID ) );
}
```

Then while querying posts use `modified` as `orderby` parameter

Comment: You have a syntax error in your third line of code,missing a `)`

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, this functionality is not natively supported by Wordpress, but that does not say it can't be done.

To accomplish this, you'll need to add a custom [`query_vars`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars), and add custom sql queries and joining these queries through the [`posts_join`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join) [`posts_orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) filters. This code was stripped from the [**Filter By Comments**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/filter-by-comments/) plugin from Kevin Ingersoll. The complete plugin can be downloaded [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/filter-by-comments/). I've tested it thoroughly, and it works despite not being updated in more than two years.

Here is the custom code that makes it all happens

```
<?php
FilterByComments::getInstance();

class FilterByComments {

    static function getInstance() {
        static $instance;
        return $instance ? $instance : $instance = new self;
    }

    private function __clone() {}


    protected function __construct() {
        add_filter('query_vars', array(&$this, 'query_vars'));
        add_filter('posts_join', array(&$this, 'posts_join'));
        add_filter('posts_orderby', array(&$this, 'posts_orderby'));
    }


    function query_vars($vars) {
        $vars[] = 'orderby_last_comment';
        return $vars;
    }


    function posts_join($sql) {
        global $wpdb;
        if(get_query_var('orderby_last_comment')) {
            return $sql.'
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT `comment_post_ID` AS `post`, MAX(`comment_date`) AS `date` FROM `'.$wpdb->comments.'` WHERE `comment_approved`="1" GROUP BY `post`) AS `last_comment`
                    ON `last_comment`.`post` = `'.$wpdb->posts.'`.`ID`
            ';
        }
        return $sql;
    }

    function posts_orderby($sql) {
        if(get_query_var('orderby_last_comment')) {
            return '`last_comment`.`date` DESC'.($sql !== '' ? ', '.$sql : '');
        }
        return $sql;
    }
}
?>
```

It is simple to implement via [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) or [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).You can work directly with the `query_vars` `orderby_last_comment`. To order posts by newest comment, just set `orderby_last_comment` to `true` or `1`

**USING `pre_get_posts`**

```
function order_by_newest_comment( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby_last_comment', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_by_newest_comment' );
```

**USING `WP_Query`**

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('orderby_last_comment=true');
```